# Firebase In-App Messaging - how to use new line

Tags: android, firebase, newline, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm trying to send some In-App Messaging to the users.

To keep good-looking formating here, I'd need possibility to move some text into new line in one place.

I'm trying to use `\n`, `%n` symbols in "Body" field, but none of theme works:

[image: Firebase In-App console]

I've also tried sending those messages to real devices, but they look the same as in the preview.

How can I force In-App Messaging to make new line in the specific place?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: @LittleLebowski I think I figured it out. Want to give it a try? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77484937/1759443

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It is possible!! [Unicode newline was the answer.](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/0085.html)

1. Copy the unicode new line character (it'll look like a tab). I got it from [here](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/0085.html). StackOverflow doesn't support it, so just copy it from the website I linked.
2. Paste it into the field. In my example screenshot, there are two side-by-side, the second one is selected. In the previewer, it'll look incorrect (like a few spaces).
   [image: screenshot-textfield with newlines]
3. Send the push to your device

It should look like this!!

[image: screenshot-announcement with newlines]